# Create Array without SourceFile using Exiftool

Tags: exiftool

I would like to use Exiftool to create an array of `-Artists` for all files in a directory. Using the exiftool command below works but the output is not desirable:

```
C:\exiftool.exe -Artist Dir
```

The output looks something like this:

```
======== E:/File1.jpg
Artist                          : user1
======== E:/File2.jpg
Artist                          : user2
    1 directories scanned
    2 image files read
```

I would like the output to look something like this:

```
user1_user2
```

Or at least a simple array or output like:

```
user1
user2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand upon the answer I posted in the [exiftool forums](http://u88.n24.queensu.ca/exiftool/forum/index.php/topic,8719.0.html) :
`exiftool -q -s3 -Artist DIR`

This will output each `Artist` tag on a line by itself, like your second example.

`-q` - Suppresses normal informational messages.  This will suppress the file name listings.
`-s3` - Short output format.  In this case, the addition of `3` to the option only prints the values of the tag.